# There was an error opening this document. Invalid action object

Tags: excel, vba, acrobat

I’m writing a Sub Routine in VBA to display the amount of pages in a PDF document.  Here is my code (from my module):

```
Sub PDF_Num_Pages()
   Dim tCount As Long
   Dim objAVDoc As New AcroAVDoc
   Dim objPDDoc As New AcroPDDoc
   Dim objPage As AcroPDPage
   Dim objSelection As AcroPDTextSelect
   Dim objHighlight As AcroHiliteList
   Dim pageNum As Long
   Dim strText As String

   objAVDoc.Open "C:\<path to my file>\simple1.pdf", ""
   Set objPDDoc = objAVDoc.GetPDDoc
   MsgBox objPDDoc.GetNumPages()

End Sub
```

When I run the script, Adobe Acrobat Reader opens.  Then an error appears from Adobe Acrobat:
`There was an error opening this document. Invalid action object.`

I click on OK.  The box disappears.

Then in Excel, my message box appears, displaying a -1.

The PDF is 1 page in length, and so it should display a 1.

In the `Tools->References` I have the `Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library` checked.

In my Adobe Acrobat Document (simple1) I enabled the security features.  When I double click on it, I don’t get the "Enable All Features" choice, anymore.  It automatically opens.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you simply declare an `As New AcroAVDoc` and call `objAVDoc` without first setting it to something?

Comment: @BruceWayne I'd avoid declaring it `As New` though; this tends to have undesired side-effects on the object's lifetime.

Comment: The Ole-automation objects for Adobe Acrobat (the $$$ version) don't work with Reader only. No chance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working now.  I stopped declaring the objects as new.  (Thanks Mathieu.)  I found another post; that demonstrated declaring them after creating the object; and did that.

I also ran Adobe Acrobat and did some PDF converting (I wonder if that might have set up something on my machine that was not fully set up before).  I did a "repair" as well for my Adobe Acrobat.

Windows restarts may have helped too.  Here’s the working code:

```
Sub PDF_Num_Pages()
   Dim myApp As Acrobat.AcroApp
   Dim objAVDoc As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
   Dim objPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc

   ' create an automation object that references the active copy of Acrobat
   Set myApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
   ' reference the acrobat document we loaded above
   Set objAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

   objAVDoc.Open "C:\<pdf path>simple1.pdf", ""
   Set objPDDoc = objAVDoc.GetPDDoc
   MsgBox objPDDoc.GetNumPages()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the function should be written as...

```
objAVDoc.Open("C:\<path to my file>simple1.pdf", "")
```

...just a suggestion.

Comment: Are you asking or telling?

Comment: The code looks like it is missing those brackets. This was a suggestion for an amendment that may help to fix it.

Comment: I agree that looks more correct.  But when I add those I get a syntax error.